# Use third party library (parse.com) in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, parse-platform

I am learning Angular 2 and I followed the tutorials of Egghead already, but I am pretty new to everything concerning Angular.

Now I want to do something more advanced and start using Parse.com with Angular 2.
Normally I would include the parse.com library in the index.html page via `<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.6.2.min.js"></script>`, but I want to write a ParseService via Angular 2 that I can use to manage the backend.

I can't seem to find how to include and use Parse in the service I want to write. 
This is the very basic code I want to use to test the import.

```js
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Parse} from '.../...'; // <-- This is what I want to do

@Injectable()
export class ParseService {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Creating ParseService');

        Parse.initialize('', '');
    }
}
```

I need some kind of Import at the top of the page including Parse, but from where should I get the necessary library? I already tried via `npm` but without success. Anyone already tried this?

Comment: Did you find out how to "import {Parse} from '.../...'; // <-- This is what I want to do"?  I'm stuck there as well.

Comment: have a look at my answer, you are script cdn did is wrong, if you update it may be i will create a demo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

uksz was right. You has to first install the component by the command

```
npm install --save parse
```

After that you can import it as any other component by typing

```
import {Parse} from 'parse';
```

For more info look at this link https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-require-xyz-in-ionic2-angular2/42042

Hope it helps;)

## UPDATED

With new version of angular this approach stopped to work. Here is my new step by step: how to use Parse library in Angular2

1. Install Parse component to the project

   ```
   npm install parse --save
   ```
2. Install Parse types

   ```
   npm install @types/parse --save
   ```
3. import Parse module

   ```
   const Parse: any = require('parse');
   ```
4. use Parse module

   ```
   Parse.initialize("key");
   ...
   ```

Enjoy it with intellisense;)

Comment: Hi where should const Parse occur? I'm new to Angular and trying to expand on some code I purchased. Does it go under the imports in app.component.ts if I want it to work across the entire site?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using **[OpaqueToken](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html)** in Angular2

**1**. Create a Token that is used to find an instance as below in a separate ts file.

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core'

export let name_of_The_Token = new OpaqueToken('name_Of_The_Window_Object');
```

**2.** In your **App.module**, you need to **import and declare a variable** that is the name of your window object which makes the Token as a angular2 service so that you can use properties, methods in that javascript file across your components.

```
import { name_of_The_Token } from '/* file_Path */';
declare let name_Of_The_Window_Object : any;  //below your import statements
```

Step 3: **Inject** it to providers array of your module.

```
{ provide : name_of_The_Token , useValue : name_Of_The_Window_Object }
```

Guidance to use this token in components

1. Import the token just like any other service and @Inject from angular-core

   ```
    import { name_of_The_Token } from '/* file_Path */';
    import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
   ```
2. In constructor of the component

   ```
    constructor(@Inject( name_of_The_Token ) private _serviceObject : any )
   ```
3. Any where in your component you can use the variables and methods of your javascript file as

   ```
    this._serviceObject.method1()
    this._serviceObject.variable1
    .....
   ```

**Note**: One drawback is that you will **not get intellisense**.

Overcoming it:
If you are looking for intellisense you need to **wrap the methods and variables inside an interface** and use it in the type**(instead of any)** of your token as

```
export interface myCustom {
      method1(args): return_Type;
      method2(args): void;
      .....
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do, is you need to download Parse library with:

```
npm install parse
```

Then, you need to reference it in your import in the right way - you need to specify in which folder the parse.js file is placed at.

Comment: This doesn't answer how you import Parse in angular2 as @ThijsM stated at "import {Parse} from '.../...'; // <-- This is what I want to do"