# Using Parse as a module in Angular2

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am new to Angular2 and TypeScript and I am trying to import Parse into my application. So I have installed parse as a node module using `npm install parse --save` and I can see the parse folder inside the `node_modules` folder.
Now, in my app.ts file, I am trying the following code but I don't know why is this giving errors.

```
import {Parse} from 'parse';
```

It gives the error that it

> cannot find the module 'parse'

.

I also tried the following code,

```
import {} from 'parse'
```

and it works without errors but I don't know how do I use the Parse object now.

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: included `parse` js in html , ryt?

Comment: No, could you please tell me what should be the path of the src, I have tried ../node_modules/... but not working.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886900/use-third-party-library-parse-com-in-angular-2/42301007) is it solved). I put the step by step how i solved it here.

1. Install Parse component to the project

   ```
   npm install parse --save
   ```
2. Install Parse types

   ```
   npm install @types/parse --save
   ```
3. import Parse module

   ```
   const Parse: any = require('parse');
   ```
4. use Parse module

   ```
   Parse.initialize("key");
   ...
   ```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: I had to declare a var in typings.d.ts as => declare var require: any;

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the `parse` module so that is recognized by typescript.

You can declare the `parse`module yourself with something like this:

```
declare module 'parse' {
    var parse: any;
    export { parse };
    export default parse;
}
```

Or you can use the typing definitions provided by Definitely Typed:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd